# How should I find y in $23y \pmod {63} = 1$ using Extended Euclid's Theorem?

Tags: number-theory

How do I find a integer $y$ here such that $23y = 1 \pmod {63}$ . I got it using hit and trial. But how to approach using the extended Euclidean algorithm?

Comment: Have you tried searching 'extended euclidean algorithm' on this site?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extended Euclidean Algorithm for Modular Inverse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/747342/extended-euclidean-algorithm-for-modular-inverse). Also, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/776859/modulo-inverse-using-extended-euclidean), and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1505902/using-extended-euclidean-algorithm-to-find-multiplicative-inverse), and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3331449/using-the-euclidean-algorithm-how-to-find-the-inverse-of-41-in-z131). And possibly many more.

Comment: yes, but didn't find anything helpful for this problem.

Comment: Even if this question has been asked many times before, you can still add your own efforts. If you try *using* the extended Euclidean algorithm, and you get stuck, you can write down your steps. This allows us to better help you. See [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *extended Euclidean algorithm*   is based on the observation that at each step of the basic Euclidean algorithm, the remainder is a linear combination of the two given numbers.

Namely , setting $a=r_0$, $b=r_1$ ($a>b$), the $i$-th division is
$$r_{i-1}=q_ir_i+r_{i+1}\iff r_{i+1}=r_{i-1}-q_ir_i\qquad(i\ge 1),$$
so we have a linear recurrence relation of order $2$ between the remainders, hence between the Bézout relation expressing each remainder in function of $a$ and $b$: $r_i=u_ia+v_ib$.

This can be  displayed in the following layout:
\begin{array}{crrrrrl}
n&r_i &&v_i&u_i&&q_i \\\hline
&63&&0&1\\
1&23&&1&0&&2 \\\hline
2&17&&-2&1&&1\\3&6&&3&-1&&2\\
4&5&&-8&3&&1 \\
\color{red}5&\color{red}1&&\color{red}{11}&\color{red}{-4}\\
\hline
\end{array}
Therefore $\; y\equiv 11\mod 63$.